# Google maps not loading in bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display the google map in my tab and the map(which otherwise displays fine) does not display in the tab.

Here is my script that I included:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBEIelknc9KeDqQGJvtv6iamt_qctPT0Y4&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
     <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBEIelknc9KeDqQGJvtv6iamt_qctPT0Y4&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>

<script>
      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 43.6525, lng: -79.3816},
          zoom: 13
        });
        var card = document.getElementById('pac-card');
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
        var strictBounds = document.getElementById('strict-bounds-selector');

        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(card);

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

        // Bind the map's bounds (viewport) property to the autocomplete object,
        // so that the autocomplete requests use the current map bounds for the
        // bounds option in the request.
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
        infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
        });

        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
          infowindow.close();
          marker.setVisible(false);
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          if (!place.geometry) {
            // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
            // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
            window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
            return;
          }

          // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
          if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
          }
          marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
          marker.setVisible(true);

          var address = '';
          if (place.address_components) {
            address = [
              (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
            ].join(' ');
          }

          infowindowContent.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
          infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
          infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = address;
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

        // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
        // Autocomplete.
        function setupClickListener(id, types) {
          var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
          radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            autocomplete.setTypes(types);
          });
        }

        setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
        setupClickListener('changetype-address', ['address']);
        setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
        setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);

        document.getElementById('use-strict-bounds')
            .addEventListener('click', function() {
              console.log('Checkbox clicked! New state=' + this.checked);
              autocomplete.setOptions({strictBounds: this.checked});
            });
      }
    </script>
```

```html
 <div class="bs-example">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionA">Section A</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionB">Section B</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionC">Section C</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#sectionD">Section D</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div id="sectionA" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                        <h3>Section A</h3>
                        <p>Aliquip placeat salvia cillum iphone. Seitan aliquip quis cardigan american apparel, butcher voluptate nisi qui. Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica. Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh dreamcatcher synth.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="sectionB" class="tab-pane fade">
                        <h3>Section B</h3>
                        <p>Vestibulum nec erat eu nulla rhoncus fringilla ut non neque. Vivamus nibh urna, ornare id gravida ut, mollis a magna. Aliquam porttitor condimentum nisi, eu viverra ipsum porta ut. Nam hendrerit bibendum turpis, sed molestie mi fermentum id. Aenean volutpat velit sem. Sed consequat ante in rutrum convallis. Nunc facilisis leo at faucibus adipiscing.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="sectionC" class="tab-pane fade">
                        <h3>Section C</h3>
                        <p>Vestibulum nec erat eu nulla rhoncus fringilla ut non neque. Vivamus nibh urna, ornare id gravida ut, mollis a magna. Aliquam porttitor condimentum nisi, eu viverra ipsum porta ut. Nam hendrerit bibendum turpis, sed molestie mi fermentum id. Aenean volutpat velit sem. Sed consequat ante in rutrum convallis. Nunc facilisis leo at faucibus adipiscing.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="sectionD" class="tab-pane fade">
                          <div id="pac-container">
                          <input id="pac-input" type="text"
                              placeholder="Enter a location">
                        </div>
                        <div id="map" style="height:200px;"></div>
                        <div id="infowindow-content">
                        <img src="" width="16" height="16" id="place-icon">
                        <span id="place-name"  class="title"></span><br>
                        <span id="place-address"></span>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                <div class="pac-card col-md-6" id="pac-card">
                  <div>
                    <div id="title">
                      Autocomplete search
                    </div>
                    <div id="type-selector" class="pac-controls">
                      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-all" checked="checked">
                      <label for="changetype-all">All</label>

                      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-establishment">
                      <label for="changetype-establishment">Establishments</label>

                      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-address">
                      <label for="changetype-address">Addresses</label>

                      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-geocode">
                      <label for="changetype-geocode">Geocodes</label>
                    </div>
                    <div id="strict-bounds-selector" class="pac-controls">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="use-strict-bounds" value="">
                      <label for="use-strict-bounds">Strict Bounds</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

              </div>
            </div>



        </div>
```

Comment: where is your script?

Comment: Here is my script. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. The map loads if not in tab but does not load in tab.

Comment: you mean map inside sectionA or sectionB like that?

Comment: Yes in this case map inside section D does not show up.

Comment: Any idea Dinesh?

Comment: Solved!!! I added all the java script and the html in the same tab content and it fixed the problem. If anyone is looking for something similar please feel free to use my code.